# Управление звонком через USB

Tags: usb, embedded, микроконтроллеры

Программа в определенный день недели и момент времени подает звонок.

Было принято в качестве проводника выбрать *usb hid*.

Созданием устройства, прошивкой микроконтроллера будут заниматься другие люди.
Мне нужно - разработать саму программу для работы с данным устройством.

В какой среде можно разрабатывать такую программу?

Answer (score 1):

Непонятно как выбор среды разработки связан с вашей задачей. Чем умеете пользоваться, тем и пользуйтесь. Также вы не указали ОС, под которую планируете писать. Я пишу софт для Windows под HID устройства, используя mcHID.dll (легко гуглятся примеры) под дельфи. Это наиболее простой вариант, из виденных мной на просторах сети.

Answer (score 1):

Среда разработки особой роли не играет. Тут более важно, какую библиотеку вы решили использовать и с какой ОС работаете. Например, и в Windows, и в Linux часто используют библиотеку libusb.

Если нет опыта работы с USB, то ознакомьтесь:

- [USB для программистов микроконтроллеров](http://njnmnp.narod.ru/note/USB_for_programmer.pdf);
- Агуров П. Интерфейс USB. практика использования и программирования. СПб.: БХВ, 2004.

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от драйвера. Не буду экстрасенсом, если скажу, что скорее всего драйвер будет под Windows x86, написанный на Visual C++

Драйвер должен высунуть наружу некие функции/методы работы с вашим USB девайсом, с вероятностью 99% API будет совместимо с C/C++

Ну а дальше самое простое взять Visual C++ и написать окружение работающее с этими API методами.

В качестве альтернатив можно рассмотреть и другие языки, но это будет чуток сложнее, поскольку будет подразумевать переброску мостика из сишного API, хотя если рассмотреть вариант создания портабельного приложения переход на Java может окупиться.